# Temporary variables created when using const reference

Tags: c++

I am making some matrix class and I was wondering when a temporary object is created it is local to the function right? so it should get out of scope when function return but I don't know why that don't happen in this case I can use it after the function have returned.

Here is an example, this is the constructor:

```
int *data;   //member of class
Matrix3(const int (&ar)[N*N])
{
    data = const_cast<int*>(ar);
}
```

and here is how I use it:

```
Matrix3 m = { {1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6} };
```

Now I can still access that object from the destructor through the `data` pointer is this normal? the temporary variable is created on the heap then?!

Comment: data is inside an instance of the class so as long as the instance is alive you can access it

Comment: so if i didnt assigned it to data would it continue also to be alive until class is destroyed?

Comment: If I understand what your saying yes

Comment: data is just a pointer, where does the array get stored????

Comment: so to be clear , it creates the varaible as local to the object? not th function?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question. Do you want to know whether the pointer "data" still exists after the function has returned, or whether the data which is pointed TO still exists after the function has returned?

Comment: yes, date will exist sure am asking for the array it pointed to why is it still valid and i can acess the array from the data pointer in the destructor of that class?

Comment: No. After you hit the semi-colon on your line, the array is gone.

Comment: If you are seeing the array is still there, then it is just lingering in memory and hasn't been overwritten yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lifetime of a temporary ends at the semicolon of the statement or declaration that introduced it, not at the end of the function. (Otherwise, an innocuous loop could easily cause a stack overflow.)

If you use a reference to an object after its lifetime has ended (such as the array here), then you get *undefined behavior*. C++ does not keep track of dead objects in order to tell you when you are using one. You happen to find the information from the dead array. But something else could have reused the memory, or it could have been returned to the system and you could get a segfault.

Avoid dangling references and pointers. Do not suppose that if it works in a test-case, that it works in the field.

Comment: @aaronman Named objects are destroyed when they go out of scope (at the end of a block, or at program termination). Unnamed objects, a.k.a. temporaries, are destroyed at the end of a statement, unless the statement is a declaration of a reference bound to the temporary.

Comment: oh my bad, I was thinking of named vars not temps, the code in that question must of confused me :)

Answer (score 0):

After your line executes, the temporary array is destroyed and the data pointer becomes invalid.

Comment: so it is just that this memory isnt used by any part yet or what ? why can i still acess it from the destructor that was my point?

Answer (score 0):

```
int *data; // is a member, so it goes out of scope when the object is destroyed
```

However, if you declared it in a function like this:

```
void someFunction() {

    int *data;


}

// pointer is lost now and is inaccessible
```